# How can I mint a very limited number of NFTs on Kadena blockchain using pact smart contract?

Tags: pact, nft, pact-lang

I want to mint only a few NFT tokens on Kadena blockchain that I want to use as a giveaway for full access to my platform. I do not want to create my own coin on Kadena for now. I have seen their Pact smart contract for KIP-0011 named poly-fungible-v1 but I'm unable to find any help on the impleentation. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For implementation you can checkout any of the existing projects.
You can search on the chainweb explorer for code snippets. Some results [here](https://explorer.chainweb.com/mainnet/txsearch?q=poly-fungible-v1)

That should give you some examples :)

Btw, strictly speaking, you don't need to implement KIP-0011 to make an NFT, that standard just makes it easier to be compatible with things. However as of time of writing (22 Mar 2022) there's a poly-fungible-v2 coming out which would be better for compatibility. But you could always "upgrade" your smart contract to support any new interfaces

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.

Now, my next questions are:
1- minting an nft through pact, is it just defining a schema and adding a few items to the table with unique IDs/Hashes or am I missing something here?
2- Do I have to create a ledger within the smart contract to keep track of the NFTs? Or can I do without it?
3- How to validate if an nft has been minted in a proper way?
4- Is it possible to view an nft on kadena explorer?

Comment: Those all are valid questions but each probably deserves its own stack overflow post :) (this will help others discover the answers in the future)
Happy to answer them on the separate posts